# Can I use sys.exit() to stop a Tkinter program

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Is there a problem with using `sys.exit()` to stop a Tkinter program?

I know normally people use `root.destroy()` why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course but it will terminate the entire program, including your app.

According to here: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/66698/exit-a-tkinter-gui-program. `root.destroy` is a safe, dependable way to exit your Tkinter app. From the link:

> destroy() just terminates the mainloop and deletes all widgets. So it seems to be safer if you call your app from another Tkinter app, or if you have multiple mainloops.

Answer (score 1):

I use both. root.destroy() is used to destroy all windows (parent, child) within the root tkinter instance, but it doesn't end the python program.

sys.exit() stops all active applications used by python.

In short, if your python code runs a tkinter GUI exclusively and it's functionality ends after the window is closed then use both root.destroy() followed by sys.exit() to effectively end the session.